# Adding a command to a radiobutton in a ListView

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've a ListView which iterates over a number of questions which the end user is required to answer with radiobuttons or checkboxes.

The ViewModel specifies "TheQuestions" as:

```
TheQuestions = new ObservableCollection<Question>();
TheQuestions.Add(new Question
{
  Id = 123,
  Attribute1 = Value1,
  TheQuestion = "Blah blah?",
  Answer = false,
});
```

The ListView looks like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TheQuestions, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="{Binding TheQuestion}" />
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <RadioButton Command="{ ?? }"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  GroupName="{Binding Id,Mode=TwoWay}" Text="Yes" TextColor="Green" />
            <RadioButton Command="{Binding ??}" GroupName="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="No" TextColor="Red" />
        </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
   </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Later on I will add checkboxes and entries as well to a number of questions. I'm struggling when comes to populating my viewmodel with the selected answer. Is it doable or should I consider another approach?

Comment: why wouldn't you just bind IsChecked to your VM?

Comment: Good question, I went down the rabbit hole and didnt think about a solution as simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could binding the RadioButton's command directly to ViewModel so that you don't need to define it in Model multi-times .

#### in Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App32"
             x:Class="App32.MainPage"
             
             x:Name="Page" // set name of ContentPage
             
             >
```

```
<RadioButton Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Page}, Path=BindingContext.RadioCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  GroupName="{Binding Id,Mode=TwoWay}" Text="Yes" TextColor="Green" />
            <RadioButton Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Page}, Path=BindingContext.RadioCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" GroupName="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="No" TextColor="Red" />
```

#### In your ViewModel

```
public ICommand RadioCommand { get; set; }
```

```
public xxxViewModel()
{
   TheQuestions = new ObservableCollection<Question>();
   TheQuestions.Add(new Question
   {
    Id = 123,
    Attribute1 = Value1,
    TheQuestion = "Blah blah?",
    Answer = false,
   });

   RadioCommand = new Command((obj)=> {

                var model = obj as Question;

                var answer = model.Answer;

                //do something you want 



            });

}
```